# To merge address or not to merge addresses?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, merge

Working on a sqlalchemy python flask postgresql project but not sure if I should merge my tables together. I first started off with company address in early development stages now I have another address table.

Should I keep these separate or should these be merged to a global Address table?

```
UserAddress
CompanyAddress
```

If I do merge them together to an Address Table it would be something like the following... however in the long run I still have more user_id than company_id and would mostly be blank.

```
Address
-user_id
-company_id
```

Companies and user can have multiple addresses... so this is why I'm thinking of using this approach but in the long run. Also I'm not sure if it is a good idea as for maintaining this. Or should I leave them as is and maintain them separately?

Thanks! And if possible, share your experience in dealing with similar situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty difficult to answer your question, there are some points to take care of:

1. If `UserAddress` and `CompanyAddress` have exactly the same fields and they can be interchangeable between Users and Companies and you won't want to make queries like all of the UserAddress or all of the CompanyAddress, my advice would be to merge those in the same Address table, as they represent the same entity for you in the database model.
2. If there are some `user addresses` that don't make sense as a `company address` or if you will add values for `company address` not present in `user address`, I recommend you to keep those tables separated, because they don't represent the same entity (a user address is not the same as a company address).
3. If you will make operations like "all of the addresses", or searching for text inside all of the addresses, I think I'd make sense to use inheritance. You can accomplish this by saving common fields into one Address table and the specific ones in separated user/company address tables keeping a foreign key to the main Address table, then you reference User/Company Address tables in the User/Company tables respectively.

Your safe bet is to keep the tables separated, you can always merge them later if it makes sense, but if you feel really confident and the tables are (and you think they will be) exactly the same, and you won't be querying for user or company addresses (which will require a lot of joins), just merge them into one table.

Hope it helps,

Comment: User address and company address probably wont be interchangeable. And I'd be querying as following `select * from address where user_id=x` for users and similarly for company query as well. So SQLALCHEMY should be like `Address.filter(Address.user_id != None)).all()` The table columns are similar just the fact that user_id and company_id either one will have to be filled in. My concern is that company_id column will mostly be blank and ongoing maintainability

Comment: Then, my advice would be not to join the tables. Another question: will you need to query "all of the addresses"? In that case I'd make sense to use inheritance, saving common fields into one table and the different ones in separated user/company address tables keeping a foreign key to the main Address table.

Comment: to keep common fields into one table and different one in others? Most of them are similar. The only real unique columns are for user_id and company_id. I don't usually query for all addresses .. its usually specific to either user_id or company_id. As for the common fields, I have an abstract model class that I used for address.

Comment: Yes, I think the solution of keeping common fields into one table is somewhere in the middle of splitting and joining tables... My advice for you is not to join the tables, as they don't mean the same...